# Writing thesis paper: Grammar correction tool

Tags: tools, grammar, microsoft-word

I have been writing my master's thesis. My supervisor is helping me a lot to format and correct the spelling and grammar. But I think he has been using some Microsoft word addons  which looks like the following image:
[image]

It shows that it has been formatted in English UK format.

Does anybody know what the tool is? or I will appreciate any tool suggestion.

Comment: I agree with RJo's answer. I would also recommend [Grammarly](http://grammarly.com). I'm always using it. They have an awesome extension for your browser that helps you while you writing.

Comment: This needed the screenshot to make sense as a question.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your screenshot, your supervisor is using Word's builtin functions (not an addon). The following short answer pertains to Word 2010 for Windows, and should still be relevant if you are using a different version.

Click your Review tab and you will a number of editing groups (see screenshot).

[image: Word's "Review" tab for setting language and tracking changes]

For a longer answer about Word and UK English, see http://word.tips.net/T001678_Changing_to_UK_English.html